# Codeigniter call one's Class method inside another Classe's method

Tags: php, codeigniter, crm

To be very specific - there is CRM system written in Codeigniter called Rise. I would like to make (automatically) an expense entry ( `call save() method of an Expenses class` ) each time someone logs in ( `inside save_timelog() method of a Projects class` ) time manually.

Expense Controller:

```
function save() {

    validate_submitted_data(array(
        "id" => "numeric",
        "expense_date" => "required",
        "category_id" => "required",
        "amount" => "required"
    ));

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $target_path = get_setting("timeline_file_path");
    $files_data = move_files_from_temp_dir_to_permanent_dir($target_path, "expense");
    $has_new_files = count(unserialize($files_data));

    $data = array(
        "expense_date" => $this->input->post('expense_date'),
        "title" => $this->input->post('title'),
        "description" => $this->input->post('description'),
        "category_id" => $this->input->post('category_id'),
        "amount" => unformat_currency($this->input->post('amount')),
        "project_id" => $this->input->post('expense_project_id'),
        "user_id" => $this->input->post('expense_user_id'),
        "files" => $files_data
    );

    <.. ETC. CHECKING FILES ..>

    $save_id = $this->Expenses_model->save($data, $id);

    if ($save_id) {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "data" => $this->_row_data($save_id), 'id' => $save_id, 'message' => lang('record_saved')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, 'message' => lang('error_occurred')));
    }

}
```

Projects Controller:

```
function save_timelog() {

    $this->access_only_team_members();
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $start_time = $this->input->post('start_time');
    $end_time = $this->input->post('end_time');
    $note = $this->input->post("note");
    $task_id = $this->input->post("task_id");


    if (get_setting("time_format") != "24_hours") {
        $start_time = convert_time_to_24hours_format($start_time);
        $end_time = convert_time_to_24hours_format($end_time);
    }

    $start_date_time = $this->input->post('start_date') . " " . $start_time;
    $end_date_time = $this->input->post('end_date') . " " . $end_time;

    $start_date_time = convert_date_local_to_utc($start_date_time);
    $end_date_time = convert_date_local_to_utc($end_date_time);

    $data = array(
        "project_id" => $this->input->post('project_id'),
        "start_time" => $start_date_time,
        "end_time" => $end_date_time,
        "note" => $note ? $note : "",
        "task_id" => $task_id ? $task_id : 0,
    );

    if (!$id) {
        //insert mode
        $data["user_id"] = $this->input->post('user_id') ? $this->input->post('user_id') : $this->login_user->id;
    } else {
        //edit mode
        //check edit permission
        $this->check_timelog_updte_permission($id);
    }

    $save_id = $this->Timesheets_model->save($data, $id);
    if ($save_id) {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "data" => $this->_timesheet_row_data($save_id), 'id' => $save_id, 'message' => lang('record_saved')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, 'message' => lang('error_occurred')));
    }

}
```

So now what I'm trying to do is inside Projects controller, save_timelog() method just below these lines:

<...>

```
    if (!$id) {
        //insert mode
        $data["user_id"] = $this->input->post('user_id') ? $this->input->post('user_id') : $this->login_user->id;
    } else {
        //edit mode
        //check edit permission
        $this->check_timelog_updte_permission($id);
    }

    /* CREATING A SAMPLE ARRAY WITH STATIC DATA FOR AN EXAMPLE EXPENSE ENTRY */

    $a = array(
        "expense_date" => '2018-03-13',
        "title" => 'Cat Food',
        "description" => 'Sheba, Felix, KiteKat',
        "category_id" => '85',
        "amount" => '500',
        "project_id" => '84',
        "user_id" => '10',
        "files" => $files_data
    );

    /* TRYING TO SAVE/SEND EXAMPLE ARRAY TO Expenses Class save() method (?) */

    $b = $this->Expenses_model->save($a);

    /* RESULT (?) */

    $save_id = $this->Timesheets_model->save($data, $id);

    if ($save_id) {
        echo json_encode(
          array(
            array(
              "success" => true,
              "data" => $this->_timesheet_row_data($save_id),
              'id' => $save_id,
              'message' => lang('record_saved')
            ),
            array(
              "success" => true,
              "data" => _row_data($b),
              'id' => $save_id,
              'message' => lang('record_saved')
            )
          )
        );
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, 'message' => lang('error_occurred')));
    }
```

<.. Closing save_timelog() method ..>

However it surely doesn't work and all I get is `"POST http://rise.test/index.php/projects/save_timelog 500 (Internal Server Error)"`.

I also load Expenses model and Expenses categories model in Projects _construct():

Projects Controller:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("Project_settings_model");
    $this->load->model("Expense_categories_model");
    $this->load->model("Expenses_model");
}
```

I also contacted developers of Rise with following question/answer:

> **Me:**
>
> In Projects controller save_timelog() method I just want to call
> Expenses controller save() method, and if save_timelog() is successful
> I would like to save an Expense ( $this->Expenses_model->save($data,
> $id); ) with appropriate data. Could be static values for now for
> $data array in save() method - just to find out it's working.
>
> **Rise Devs:**
>
> Hi, You are doing almost right. Just remove the 2nd parameter $id. It
> should be used only for update.  $this->Expenses_model->save($data)

Would really appreciate any help and directions! Thanks.

Comment: Well firstly check your error logs. If you don't have any- enable error reporting. Internal server error can mean so many things it's not a great debugging starting point.

Comment: Alex, thank you! It helped to check out error log file!